# How to proper evaluate a small script with Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I have a JavaScript script simillar to the following

```
var base = 1
var next = myPackage.MyClass.getResult(base);
```

And the following class defined in package myPackage

```
public class MyClass{
  public static getResult(final int base){
    //Inner logic
  return result; //Returns another class defined by me
}
```

Now, the eval(String script, Bindings n) method of ScriptEngine returns supposedly the result of a script, such as where in the example

```
ScriptEngine engine;= new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
bindings = new SimpleBindings();
engine.eval("1 + 1", bindings);
```

the eval call returns 2, I figured I could do something of the kind:

```
ScriptEngine engine;= new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
bindings = new SimpleBindings();
String baseScript = "var base = 1; var result = myPackage.MyClass.getResult(base);"
String script = baseScript + "result.toString()";
Object result = engine.eval(script, bindings);
```

But the result of this is always null, although it evaluates correctly the getResult(base) method (if I place a breakpoint inside, I can detect the call is made and the logic done correctly).

Why is the result always null and how should this be done correctly?

Edit: full code example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
        String baseScript = "var base = 1; var result = Packages.myPackage.MyClass.getResult(base);";
        String script = baseScript + "result.toString()";
        Object result = engine.eval(script, bindings);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

package myPackage;
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass.ResultClass getResult(final int base) {
        return new MyClass.ResultClass().setString(base);
    }

    public static class ResultClass{
        private String str;

        public MyClass.ResultClass setString(int val){
            if(val < 10) {str = String.valueOf(val);}
            else str = "0";
            return this;
        }
        public String getString(){
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please create a [mcve] before posting.   Once all compilation errors are fixed, your code works fine: https://jdoodle.com/a/6h4

Comment: @Misha I created a minimal functional example, and it works too. I still can't get a grasp why doesn't it work on my original project.

Comment: the method you called from inside your script (`getResult`) probably just returned `null` and it had nothing to do with nashorn.